# mysql query issue: 'like' not working as expected

Tags: mysql

I am trying to select rows for which the column 'cats' does not include the string 'people-and-activities'. The string 'cats' can be '', NULL, or a non-empty value.

```
select ref from images where (url like 'parks%')  and ((not (cats like '%people-and-activities%')));
10634 rows in set
```

The previous reply is incorrect. This one appears correct.

```
 select ref,caption,cats from images where (url like 'parks%')  and  (cats like '%people-and-activities%') ; 
 647 rows in set
```

What I don't understand is that numbers do not add up:

```
 select ref,caption,cats from images where (url like 'parks%');
 13600 rows in set

 select ref,caption,cats from images where (url like 'parks%')  and ((not (cats like '%people-and-activities%')) or (cats like '%people-and-activities%')) ;
 11281 rows in set
```

Could someone explain the mystery to me ? Thanks

Comment: Is `cats` a **nullable** field?

Comment: You have Nulls in data